# Azure API Management import Tags from Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

I import Azure-Functions to Api-Management.
I like to get Tags to Api-Management so I can group my functions.

Is there a way to add Tags in C# functions that is added to  Azure-Functions and then import to Api-Management ?

Here is a sample code of a Azure function.
I like to add Tags?
Is there a way to add Tags?
[image]

The End result is in API-Management.
Here I have manualy added a tag to a function for grouping.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried a sample C# Azure Functions code to import tags to Azure API-Management.***

**Code**  :

```c
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp49
{
    public class BranchesFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BranchesFunction> _logger;

        public BranchesFunction(ILogger<BranchesFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("BranchesV1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/branches")] HttpRequestData req,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request for BranchesV1.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to the BranchesV1 Azure Function!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**swagger.json**  :

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "My API",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/branches": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [ "branch" ],
        "summary": "BranchesV1",
        "operationId": "get-branchesv1",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful response"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**  :

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above URL, I got output in the browser like below:-

[image]

I  **published**  the above code to the Azure Function app like below:-

[image]

The function code ran successfully in Azure Function in Portal like below:-

[image]

I added the above functions  **swagger.json**  file to OpenAPI specification like below:-

[image]

[image]

After creating the API using the swagger.json file, I can see the below tag is been added to the API’s OpenAPI specification file.

[image]

[image]